# VBA using one macro to activate a different block of codes within the macro depending on which button the user has clicked on

Tags: vba, user-input

So I have several modules and all of them are basically the same code except for the fact that each one of them filter different items on the same column of a table and then prints.

It has no issues so far since I assign each different macro to its respective button within Excel.

I was wondering if there was a "neater" way to do it by using **IF FUNCTION** within the macro based on what icon (button) the user has pressed.

[image]

So I would have one big macro - if user pressed on one of those 4 images, the macro would run a block of code instead of the other ones. The same for the other 3 images.

While trying to find the answer to this, I stumbled across a post where it said something about **USER-INPUT**, after reading the post it made sense that my question could be solved if I could somehow store the **USER-INPUT** somewhere. I have not gotten to that part of my VBA studies yet and I do not even know if it is possible in VBA for this specific task I am trying to accomplish, which is why I am here asking.

So the code would go something like this (please remember I could be just rambling at this point):

```
If USER INPUT = X Then
Range("A1:G31").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="FILTER TO A"
ELSEIf USER INPUT = Y Then
Range("A1:G31").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="FILTER TO B"
ELSEIf USER INPUT = Z Then
Range("A1:G31").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="FILTER TO C"
..and so on
```

***USER-INPUT** here would be "what icon the user pressed".*

This would help greatly when I have to make a tiny adjustment to the macro (one of the examples: change column size) - I would need to do it only once, instead of changing it for every single MODULE.

Thanks.

Comment: 'Select Case' would work if you're capturing a button press in a script;, however, code tied to each command button seems to perform the same actions without having to capture and dimension a click.

Comment: If you have shapes which all call the same Sub then within that sub `Application.Caller` will be the name of the clicked-on shape.